# how to predict most frequent purchased item in e-commerce?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-mining, algorithms, ai

i have the following dataset:
[image]

witch its market transaction dataset and i need to predict the most frequent purchased items based on transaction history, for example: if sara bought milk and cookies every begining of month, then its expected to buy it again in next begining of month. **what is the most appropriate algorithm to predict such thing?**

Comment: You may consider using Markov Processes, to answer questions like 'which is the most likely item Sara will buy after buying milk?'.

Comment: is logistic regression suitable for event ocuuring prediction?